# Why the form is updated only after the exception is thrown

Tags: c#, serial-port, xbee

I am working on a winform program that mainly involves COM port communication between Xbee and PC. Please allow me to show you the problem first:

Notes:

1. don't worry about the delegate function, its just checking the returning bytes
2. The program works before, i just added high speed setting today. So
   for xbee device, I have to start with 9600 speed, then change to
   whatever I need, which is 38400. However, once I set it to 38400,
   without power cycle the xbee. When i connect the device next   time
   , the speed remain @38400. that's the reason for me to add the
   if(initial_fail) block that try to connect with another baud_rate.
3. Please follow the comment which I marked with numbers

   ```
       try
       {
           portBuffer.Clear();
           myComPort.Write(myxbee.myxbee_cmd.cmd_mode, 0, myxbee.myxbee_cmd.cmd_mode.Length);   //RETURN OK <CR> 

           IAsyncResult res = d.BeginInvoke(null, null);
           if (res.IsCompleted == false)
           {
               res.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(2000, false);
               if (res.IsCompleted == false)
                   initial_fail = 1; //1. start from here, once there is a timeout, set the initial_fail to 1, Time-out because the baudrate is not sync
                if (d.EndInvoke(res) == false)
                  throw new Exception("Failing to enter the cmd mode");
           }
       }
       catch (ApplicationException e)
       {
           MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
           return false;
       }
       catch (Exception e)
       {
           MessageBox.Show("Error at step 1: {0}", e.Message);
           return false;
       }
       //2. here is the new code I added today
       if (initial_fail == 1)
       {
           myComPort.BaudRate = 38400; //3. Here I changed the speed and gui text
           cmbBaudRate.Text = "38400"; //PROBLEM: when Im doing step by step debug, seems like these two lines doesnt get executed. Winform GUI remain unchanged
           try
           {

               portBuffer.Clear();
               myxbee.command_buffer.Clear();
               dummy = "05";
               dummy_byte = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(dummy);
               myxbee.command_buffer.AddRange(myxbee.myxbee_cmd.data_rate); 
               myxbee.command_buffer.AddRange(dummy_byte);
               myxbee.command_buffer.Add(myxbee.myxbee_cmd.line_feed);
               myComPort.Write(myxbee.command_buffer.ToArray(), 0, myxbee.command_buffer.ToArray().Length);
               IAsyncResult res1 = d.BeginInvoke(null, null);
               if (res1.IsCompleted == false)
               {
                   res1.AsyncWaitHandle.WaitOne(1000, false);
                   if (res1.IsCompleted == false)
                       throw new ApplicationException("Timeout"); 
                       //4. since the winform hasnt shown any bd_rate change, the program will throw a time-out here again 
               }
               if (d.EndInvoke(res1) == false)
                   throw new Exception("Fail in setting data rate to 38400");
               chkHighSpeed.Checked = true;
               high_speed_set = 1;
               MessageBox.Show("Xbee high speed");
           }
           catch (ApplicationException e)
           {
               MessageBox.Show(e.Message);
               return false;
               //5. BUT AFTER THIS TIMEOUT message, the winform's GUI will be updated to 38400, and rerun the whole test will pass
           }
   ```

This is the part of GUI looks like:
[image]

So my question is why only after the timeout exception, then baud-rate will be updated?

Answer (score 0):

the problem came from the fact that you make your process on the same thread than ui.
SO UI can be frozen by your com process.
you can use doevents method which update UI to solve your problem but it isn't the best way in your case.
use a background workder to launch your com process on another thread.

Comment: here a url fo a backgroundworker sample  http://www.dotneat.net/2009/02/10/BackgroundworkerExample.aspx